# Set Dockerfile path as the same directory

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

My dockerfile and source code are in the same directory, so my cloudbuild.yaml file has '.' as the argument.
[image]

However, I am getting this error:
[image]

I already specified path '.', but its looking for a different path /workspace/Dockerfile.

My cloudbuil.yaml file:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '-t'
      - gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_API_NAME
      - .
    id: docker_build
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_API_NAME
    id: docker_push
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], with whatever code is necessary to reproduce the issue and whatever error messages are produced, as text and not as images?

Comment: Hi there! Based on [Building container images](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers) your steps looks right. But, I am wonder if you have indeed a Dockerfile in place. I think that the issue seems to be the previous step

Comment: Can you describe how your project is organized? How do you trigger the Cloud Build job? if it's with a trigger, can you provide its configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try adding the build and dot arguments in a single quote format as below?

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args:
  - 'build'
  - '-t'
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_API_NAME'
  - '.'
```

Also, you could add a ls command prior to docker build for troubleshooting purposes, just to make sure you have the Dockerfile and source at the current directory.